# Changing font for member variables in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, syntax-highlighting

I don't think this is possible, but I'll ask anyway...

Is there some way to set the color and font to be used for class member variables in the editor? I just returned to C++ and Visual Studio after being in the Java world for the past 4 years and I'm *really* missing Jetbrains' IDEA (a killer Java IDE). I've really gotten used to having my editor use colors and fonts to indicate member functions, statics, etc...

If Visual Studio can't do it, is there a better IDE for C++ / MFC programming? Visual Studio is making me feel like I've stepped inside a time machine and have been transported back ten years. Except I'm still 38 and out of shape.

Cory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in VS 2008.  At PDC we saw a preview of VS 2010 which supposedly will allow for multiple fonts.

Comment: Looks like this feature is not yet available in VS 2010 RC1

Answer (score 1):

Not free, but [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/) is an addin for vs2005/2008 that lets you assign different colors to classes, variables, macros and functions (among other features).